# Como converter 0 para null (Erro ao inserir NULL em um campo INT a partir de uma variável)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, null, int

*Estou editando essa pergunta  para que fique mais didático para outros membros, uma vez que só há publicações abordando essa situação fora da comunidade pt-br.*

Possuo um **campo** **INT** com propriedade **UNIQUE** que pode ter valor *NULL*.

O valor que será inserido nesse campo vem de uma **variável** que pode ter valor *NULL*.
O problema é que ao fazer o **INSERT**, caso essa variável tenha valor nulo, será armazenado o valor **0** (**zero**) nesse campo, o que causará problemas ao inserir um novo registro graças à propriedade **UNIQUE**.

Segue o exemplo que gerará esse erro:

```
$varExemplo = null;
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (campoIntExemplo) VALUES ('".$varExemplo."');
$query = $mysqli->query(sql);
```

Comment: Qual vai ser a diferença de uma insert para o outro? poderia detalhar melhor?

Comment: Por que está salvando como zero? Peço que coloque um exemplo de seu `INSERT` por completo.

Comment: Editei a publicação para ser mais explicativa.

Comment: Não daria pra fazer um if e criar um insert sem o campo em questão? Assim o banco trataria de colocar null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri como resolver esse problema!

Quando são inseridos valores nulos a partir de uma variável  **PHP** em um campo **INT** do banco de dados, o **PHP** converte *null* para "" (vazio), que é um valor **STRING**, então esse valor vazio era convertido para **INT** quando chegava ao banco de dados, gerando o valor 0 (**zero**).

A solução foi dar um **UPDATE** após o **INSERT** usando o ultimo id inserido como parâmetro para o **WHERE**.

Segue exemplo:

//Atribui o valor *null* à variável **$varExemplo**

```
$varExemplo = null;
```

//Aqui eu criei a query que irá inserir o valor da variável $varExemplo no **campoIntExemplo**. OBS: A query também irá inserir *null* no campo primário **campoPk**, como esse campo é **auto_increment**, ele gerará o ID do registro automaticamente.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (campoPk, campoIntExemplo) VALUES (null,'".$varExemplo."');
$query = $mysqli->query(sql);
```

//Com a constante **insert_id** eu pego o ID gerado para o registro que geramos com o INSERT, e atribuo esse id à variável **$usuarioId**.

```
$idUsuario = mysqli->insert_id;
```

//Por fim faço um **update** utilizando o valor de $usuarioId como parâmetro.

```
$sql = "UPDATE usuario SET id_visamg = null WHERE id_visamg= 0 and id_usuario = $idUsuario";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql)
```

Agradeço muito à todo empenho do @rray em me ajudar a resolver o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar um ternário para formatar corretamente a SQL caso existe uma valor atribua à variável o próprio valor mais aspas simples (no caso de um `varchar` para tipos númericos não adicione elas) caso contrário retorne o literal null.

Isso é apenas um exemplo. É muito importante utilizar prepared statements ou sanalizar e escapar corretamente os valores enviados pelo o usuário para evitar problemas com sql injection.

```
$inputVazio = empty($_POST['inputVazio']) ? 'null' : (int) $_POST['inputVazio'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO (c1, c1, c3) VALUES('v1', $inputVazio, 'v3')";
```

Possíveis saidas:

```
INSERT INTO (c1, c2, c3) values('v1', null, 'v3')
INSERT INTO (c1, c2, c3) VALUES('v1', 'novo valor', 'v3')
```

Comment: rray, ainda assim é armazenado o valor "0" no campo tipo INT. Acredito que a única forma de fazer com que o valor do campo tipo INT seja NULL é não tentando inserir dados neste campo. Por isso seria necessário uma espécie de IF  dentro do INSERT que verifique se o valor do campo é NULL, se sim, INSERT INTO (c2)  VALUES $inputVazio; deve ser ignorado.

Comment: @HugoGuitti chegou a ver a sql gerado? nela o valor vai como zero mesmo? parece que o mysql está convertendo o valor, pois o php não faria isso já que `'null'` é um string (que é diferente de `null` sem aspas).

Comment: fiz da seguinte forma:
$inputVazio = $_POST['inputVazio'];
$inputVazio = empty($iinputVazio) ? null : $inputVazio;

Verifiquei no SQL que o valor inserido é 0. Além disso, dei echo antes e depois da inserção de dados e os dois valores mostrados pelo echo foram "".

Comment: @HugoGuitti nesse código aí falta aspas simples no `null`, é obrigatório ter elas. Olha com mais calma a resposta ou o último comentário.

Comment: Também testei com aspas simples, nesse caso os echo mostraram null mas no banco de dados foi inserido o valor 0. Mas por curiosidade, se o meu objeto é não inserir nada em um campo int, por que eu deveria atribuir um valor string à variável que será armazenada nesse campo int?

Comment: @HugoGuitti tem algum valor padrão para essa coluna, olhou isso na tabela?

Comment: O valor Default desse campo é NULL.

Comment: @HugoGuitti no php você precisa atribuir o literal `'null'` para evitar que ele convertar alguns valores como (`''`, `null`, `false`) em zero.

Comment: Mas não é isso que o exemplo que você me passou faz?

Comment: @HugoGuitti A ideia é que sua sql vá montada com `null` escrita. Se vai com zero tem algum ponto de interferencia que converte o valor.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi das minhas pesquisas, não pode ser inserido NULL em um campo int. Então a única forma seria sequer mencionar o campo no INSERT. 

Exemplo se $inputVazio tiver algum valor: INSERT INTO (c1, c2, c3) VALUES (v1, $inputVazio, v3);

Exemplo se $inputVazio for NULL: INSERT INTO (c1, c3) VALUES (v1, v3);

Ou seja, eu precisaria de algo como um "if" dentro do INSERT que exclua do script tanto c2 quanto $inputVazio.

Comment: @HugoGuitti você pode gravar `null` em qualquer tipo de campo desde que ele não seja `NOT NULL`

Comment: Então eu não sei o que pode estar convertendo esse valor, pq $inputVazio só é usada em meu código para armazenar o valor de $_POST, além do INSERT.

Comment: Resolvi o problema, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isso seja possível, sim. [Nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13340006/4551469) tem algo parecido com o que você deseja:

```
INSERT INTO etc(campo1, campo2)
VALUES
(
   (CASE campo1 WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE campo1 END),
   (CASE campo2 WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE campo2 END)
);
```

OBS: o exemplo ficou feio porque você não deu muitos detalhes de tabela/campos, mas é só adaptar.

Comment: Cara, eu tentei fazer dessa forma mas não deu certo, será que é porque eu estou utilizando uma variável concatenada no lugar de "campo1" dentro do CASE?
Segue exemplo de como estou fazendo:
(CASE '".$var1."'WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE '".$var1."' END),

Comment: Isso não deveria ser um problema; mas não seria o caso de você fazer o _if_ antes e já preencher `$var1` com o dado que deve ser gravado?

Comment: rLinhares, tentei fazer o IF antes do INSERT, conforme sugestão do rray, mas mesmo no exemplo dele o valor armazenado é 0.
Quando utilizei o seu exemplo do CASE, o valor armazenado foi NULL quando o valor de $var1 é NULL, mas o problema é que também armazenou NULL quando $var1 tinha um valor.